# Django Session variables not updating properly

Tags: python, django, forms, session

I am trying to figure out how sessions work. Basically I am trying to make a restaurant menu and store ordered food into session for further use. However, I ran into a problem and I cant figure out what might be the problem.

The problem is that if I submit the form 1st time. The success view shows the correct data.

[I click Submit (pridat) and it works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wheuq.png)

The output is:

```
('2', 1)
```

Where number 2 is food ID and 1 is the quantity. 
Then I go back to the menu and I want to update the quantity to lets say 3

[I change quantity (mnozstvo) to 3 and submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cqpq.png)

But the output is still:

```
('2', 1)
```

The weirdest thing that has me confused is the fact that for example different food, even though it should be generated the same way works and updates just fine.

If I want to "order" multiple things it works fine with some and sometime one or multiple just refuse to update properly. As I am writing this 3 out of 4 works just fine.

```
('3', 5)('4', 8)('1', 15)('2', 1)
```

I can change 3-5, 4-8 and 1-15 but the 2-1 just never ever changes.

If I restart the built in django server sometimes different pair does not update properly. This time it is 2-1 but I also had an issue that 3-5 would not update.

So I would be really happy if someone could tell me what am I doing wrong? I know I am not letting django generate form but I rather do it manually in html, but that should not be the problem, should it?

menu.html with form separated for better visibility

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'restaurant/style.css' %}" />
{% if all_food_list %}
     <center>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/menu/">Menu</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">Objednavka</a></li>
     </ul>
    <div class="clearfix">
    {% for food in all_food_list %}
    <div class="div1">
    <center>
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ food.picture.url }}" alt="{{ food.name }}">
        <h2> {{ food.name}} </h2>
        <p>Cena: {{ food.price }}czk</p>
        <p>Hmotnost: {{ food.weight}}g</p>
        <p>Zlozenie: {{ food.ingredients}}</p>



        <form action="/get_food/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
        Mnozstvo: <input id="test" type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="30" step="1" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="food_type" value="{{ food.id }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Pridat">
        </form>




    </center>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    TODO: Funkcny formular, view pre objednavku, nastavit limity div-ov.
    </div>
    </center>
{% else %}
    <p>No food available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

My views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.template import loader
    from .models import Food
    from .forms import FoodOrder

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('restaurant/index.html')
    request.session.flush()
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
def menu (request):
    all_food_list = Food.objects.order_by('name')
    template = loader.get_template('restaurant/menu.html')
    context = {
        'all_food_list': all_food_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
def get_food(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FoodOrder(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            #Food_type is db food id
            food_type = form.cleaned_data['food_type']
            #add to the session
            request.session[food_type] = quantity

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
def success(request):
    #just writes the content of session
    obsah = request.session.items()
    return HttpResponse(obsah)

# Create your views here.
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class FoodOrder(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()
    food_type = forms.IntegerField()
```

settings.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'restaurant.apps.RestaurantConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'iis_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'iis_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:\Škola\IIS\Projekt - Restaurace\media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's got something to do with the fact that, in `success`, you return foods and their quantities in tuples, instead of returning the dict itself (maybe store this data in a session key like `'food_info'` would be better).

Comment: hey, I am sorry but I dont follow. the success view is for me to see what is in session, because I dont know any other way to actually look into data saved in session (really new to whole this). It can be (and will be) removed.

So my take on your answer is that the session has correct data, it just does not show correctly because it is in tuples? 

it does not make much sense to me because right now I am already using them directly (so accessing the session) and it still is not correct.

Comment: Never mind then, I thought you were using the values returned by `success` to re-update your session. If this was the case, you would be using an incorrect data structure (`.items()` returns a `tuple`, and the session is a `dict`)

Comment: Thanks anyway. I still dont know what might be the problem. I now added `del request.session[food_type]` before `request.session[food_type] = quantity` (with try-except)  just to see if it changes anything because in my mind it should, but it still does not change anything. :/